# Where to store client connections of Server Sent Events in Node.js

Tags: node.js, redis, server-sent-events

In Stackoverflow we already have loads of Question similar to this one of mine and none of them have solutions mentioned.

I have tried to use Client Connections in Redis but that's not possible because Response Object is kind of Circular with Socket as the end and beginning. So we cannot store in Redis. Only Plain object can be store in redis. I have tried with stringifying but of no use.

For now I am using local variable to store all connections but what if the connections grows unexpectedly. My App will go offline. Which is an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: tcp sockets are local objects, backed by native code objects.  They only apply to live code and can't be stored in something like redis or on disk.  You have to just store them in memory of the process to which they belong.  There is no other choice.  If you're worried about the total number of connections, then you will need to use clustering so you have multiple servers that the connections are distributed across.

Comment: @jfriend00 You are right man. I haven't thought about this. Man your are the saviour.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for this reassurance, like the OP I was scouring the net trying to figure out a better method. Because storing them in a local variable seems so primitive, but I guess it's necessary.